# extend or merge in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an object that has some default properties in it. I want to override those properties if options have been passed to my method.

```
    myMethod: function(options){        
           var myObj = {
         prop1: _this.get('data1'),
         prop2: _this.get('data3'),
         prop3: _this.get('data4'),
       };

       if(options){
         $.extend( myObj, options );
      }
    }
```

When I do a log on myObj after the $extend is called its not showing the new data that was passed in via options

```
myMethod({prop1:"newData1", prop2:"newData2", prop3:"newData3"})
```

Comment: Thank you for making see i'm stupid :) In my code the vales I was passing was undefined. It does indeed work.

Comment: Not at all what I intended to do `:)` Glad you figured it out.

Comment: No I know I was more joking at my own expense. You really helped in making me check my input values. Thanks again. Not sure how I can give you some points without the answer been in its own answer box. If there is a way to give you points let me know will be glad to do so

Comment: I dont understand why people dont post their 'answers' as answers? this seems like a sufficient answer, but posting it as a comment makes it seem like the question is not resolved.

Comment: and that just goes to show that stackoverflow needs improvement... sometimes comments will be answers, wether realised at the time of writing or after. why not mark a comment as an answer? and create a reply marked as answer that when clicked takes you to the comment?

Answer (score 1):

Andrew Whitaker answered this in his comment above, it seems, with this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EWeTt/